# How to get TimeZone id for specified ISO country code?

Tags: java, timezone

I have a requirement where I have to convert timezone from UTC to a specific timezone and vice-versa taking into account day light saving. I am using `java.util.TimeZone` class for it. Now, issue is that there are several hundred Ids for timezone which cannot be displayed to user.

As a work around now we have decided to have country list first and list time-zones for country selected. I am not able to get `TimeZone` for an [ISO country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Officially_assigned_code_elements).

Here is code which I am currently using to convert timezones,

```
Timestamp convertedTime = null;
try{
System.out.println("timezone: "+timeZone +", timestamp: "+timeStamp);
Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        TimeZone destTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);// TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Source timezone: "+destTimeZone);
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                    DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                    DateFormat.DEFAULT,
                    locale);
        formatter.setTimeZone(destTimeZone);
        Date date = new Date(timeStamp.getTime());
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        convertedTime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        /*long sixMonths = 150L * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
        Date inSixMonths = new Date(timeStamp.getTime() + sixMonths);
        System.out.println("After 6 months: "+formatter.format(inSixMonths));
```

I need to find out timezone Id to be used in above code for given country ISO code.

---

Update: tried many things and below code gets me to list of timezones with 148 entries (which is still large). Can any one please help me to shorten it. Or, suggest some other way to either have a shorten list of timezones or get timezones for a country,

Code:

```
public class TimeZones {

private static final String TIMEZONE_ID_PREFIXES =
  "^(Africa|America|Asia|Atlantic|Australia|Europe|Indian|Pacific)/.*";

private List<TimeZone> timeZones = null;

public List<TimeZone> getTimeZones() {
  if (timeZones == null) {
     initTimeZones();
  }

  return timeZones;
}

private void initTimeZones() {
  timeZones = new ArrayList<TimeZone>();
  final String[] timeZoneIds = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
  for (final String id : timeZoneIds) {
     if (id.matches(TIMEZONE_ID_PREFIXES)) {
        timeZones.add(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
     }
  }
  Collections.sort(timeZones, new Comparator<TimeZone>() {
     public int compare(final TimeZone a, final TimeZone b) {
        return a.getID().compareTo(b.getID());
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get things working. I have created own database table with all time-zones as appearing  in windows OS and their corresponding TimeZone IDs. Conversion is done using java.util.TimeZone class.

Thanks Namal and Frank for your inputs.

Answer (score 4):

I think [ICU4J package](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/can-i-find-all-available-timezones-for-a-country) will help you.

Comment: Thanks Namal for prompt reply, nice library. But when I tested same with US as country code, it gave me big list of timezones(around 50). As per my current understanding US has four timezones(please correct me if I am wrong). How can I get a shortened list.

Comment: Hey Guys, I have to complete this task ASAP. Requesting if anyone can help me to cut short my list of timezone IDs.

Comment: @ user1474720 : I have used this library long time ago. If we don't consider Hawaii Time  and Alaska Time yes there are 4 time zones for US as Pacific Time, Mountain Time , Central Time and Eastern Time. Can you give us the list of the TimeZone for USA. Then we can check what has really happenned.

Comment: Namal, Below is list of timezones I am getting for US country code,AST, 
America/Adak, 
America/Anchorage, 
America/Atka, 
America/Boise, 
America/Chicago, 
America/Denver, 
America/Detroit, 
America/Fort_Wayne, 
America/Indiana/Indianapolis, 
America/Indiana/Knox, 
America/Indiana/Marengo, 
America/Indiana/Petersburg, 
America/Indiana/Tell_City, 
America/Indiana/Vevay, 
America/Indiana/Vincennes, 
America/Indiana/Winamac, 
America/Indianapolis, 
America/Juneau, 
America/Kentucky/Louisville, 
America/Kentucky/Monticello, 
America/Knox_IN, 
America/Los_Angeles,

Comment: America/Louisville, 
America/Menominee, 
America/Metlakatla, 
America/New_York, America/Nome, 
America/North_Dakota/Beulah, 
America/North_Dakota/Center, 
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, 
America/Phoenix, 
America/Shiprock, 
America/Sitka, 
America/Yakutat, 
CST, 
IET, 
Navajo, 
PNT, 
PST, 
Pacific/Honolulu, 
US/Alaska, US/Aleutian, 
US/Arizona, 
US/Central, 
US/East-Indiana, 
US/Eastern, 
US/Hawaii, 
US/Indiana-Starke, 
US/Michigan, 
US/Mountain, 
US/Pacific, 
US/Pacific-New

Comment: Code I am using for same is as below,  static void useICU4j(){
  try{
   String[] timeZoneIds = com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs("US");
   System.out.println("TimeZone IDs: ");
   for(int i=0;i<timeZoneIds.length;i++){
    System.out.println(timeZoneIds[i]);
   }
   
  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 }

Comment: @Namal, I would really appreciate, if you get time to look at above code/ICU4j. I have been struggling with it for more than 2 days now. have tried lot many things and nothing seems working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your list with hasSameRules()... this should reduce you selection to about 50:

iterate through -> file equal time zones -> choose the most recognizables

The country- list has to have about 200 entries with a whole lot of uninteresting ones such as Gibraltar or St Martin... don't like that idea

Comment: Hey Frank, Can you please put little more light on same. I am kinda confused if you are referring to country list or timezone list and how exactly can this be achieved. Thanks.

Comment: as the java.util TimeZone thing offers a method to compare (hasSameRules) you can group your 690 timecodes and reduce them to maybe 40 to 50 recognizable ones...

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for replying back. I tried what you mentioned. But, it returned me list of 428 timezones after using hasSameRules.  Code is below,

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < TimeZoneIds.length; i++){
      TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZoneIds[i]);
      if(i==0){
       timez.add(tz);
      }else{
       Iterator<TimeZone> iter = timez.iterator();
       boolean sameRule = false;
       while(null != iter && iter.hasNext()){
        if(tz.hasSameRules(iter.next())){
        sameRule = true;
        break;
        }
       }
       if(!sameRule){
        timez.add(tz);
        finalList.add(tz.getID());
       }
      }

Comment: was not able to add code even using four spaces to indent it as code. Disregards for same. Kindly see if I have missed anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I never tried that method before it seems not to work as intended. It shows that (as long as hasSameRules is implemented right -its java.util) there are a whole bunch of different TZs. What you can try next (just to reduce the timezones but with a loss of infomation) is to iterate over the offset an group that. You will loose all other information but the offset if you do that..

Comment: ,@Namal I was able to get a shorter list with code added to initial post. Appreciate your help if you can get it reduced.